# C# Parsing DateTime Unable to Convert String to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, xrm

I followed the string output of my date variable, and parsed according to the format, but still encountered an Format Exception.

May I know what should I change?

```
string DOB = retrieved.Entities[i].GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("Contact.birthdate").Value.ToString();
//output: 4/13/2018 12:00:00AM

DateTime DOB_formatted = DateTime.ParseExact(DOB, "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
//System.FormatException
```

---

Resolution: Convert Object to DateTime

```
DateTime DOB_formatted = Convert.ToDateTime(retrieved.Entities[i].GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("Contact.birthdate").Value);
```

Comment: Can you try:  `DateTime.ParseExact(DOB, "MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"))` and tell me if it works?

Comment: Is `.Value` on that first line not already a DateTime? If it's `object`, you may just need to cast it.

Comment: After `.Value`, it is an Object, it gives me an error if I don't convert it to string tho

Comment: @Tony thanks for your suggestion, the same error appeared.

Comment: `DateTime DOB = (DateTime)retrieved.Entities[i].GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("Contact.birthdate").Value;` <-- does that work?

Comment: Thanks @madreflection too, converting it to DateTime from Object worked

Comment: You're welcome. You should be using a cast, though. Less plumbing to go through. The cast unboxes directly. `Convert.ToDateTime` has to go through extra type checking and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ParseExact()` requires a perfect match. The `MM/dd/yyyy` format string would require `04/13/2018`, but the value is `4/13/2018 12:00:00AM`. You want `M/d/yyyy hh:mm:sstt`, and you should confirm day values don't have leading zeroes. There's also [an overload that takes an array of format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_), if you can't trust the data source to be consistent.

Finally, per the comments, the compile-time type of `Value` is `Object`. But what about run-time? There's still a good chance the run-time type is **already** a `DateTime` value, and all you need to do is cast it. Because of internationalization/culture issues, converting to string and then re-parsing back to DateTime is suprisingly expensive. Avoiding those conversions will save the computer a *ton* of work, and really help performance.

Comment: Thank you. I converted it to DateTime and it worked. Will edit my post.